# Unable to find SYSTEM_KEY_NAME in SAP HANA Azure VM backup

Tags: azure, hana, azure-backup-vault

I am trying to backup SAP HANA database which is in Azure VM by using Recovery Vault service. While running "msawb-plugin-config-com-sap-hana.sh" script file I am getting the error

> Failed to determine SYSTEM_KEY_NAME: Please specify with the '--system-key' option.
>
> Need a valid system key to create the backup key.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The script uses the command "runuser" (in my case ndbadm). When **hdbuserstore** is executed under the profile **ndadm** no keys is returned. You can copy the files **SSFS_HDB.DAT** and **SSFS_HDB.KEY** in the path returned by **hdbuserstore LIST** from a profile with valid files.

[image: Example]

Comment: I have copied the key file from the profile. But still, I am facing the issue.

Comment: Hi Mike, Please help me to resolve this error... Still am facing the system key issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the prerequisites https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-backup-sap-hana-db#prerequisites, you have to create a key in the default hdbuserstore.
You can create it by login as ndbadm:

```
su - ndbadm
```

and add the key:

```
/hana/shared/NDB/hdbclient/hdbuserstore set BACKUP YOUR_HOSTNAME:30013 SYSTEM YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Then as a root, run the script.
After running the script, you can check again as the ndbadm user if the key AZUREWLBACKUPHANAUSER is there:

```
/hana/shared/NDB/hdbclient/hdbuserstore list
```

and delete your previously created key:

```
/hana/shared/NDB/hdbclient/hdbuserstore delete BACKUP
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz Chomin,  Thanks for the update. Now the error has been resolved...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to **SAP Note 2853601 - Why is Nameserver Port Used in HDBUSERSTORE for SAP Application Installation.**

In an MDC - nameserver port (e.g. 30013) is used in hdbuserstore instead of indexserver port (e.g. 30015) for a tenant DB.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE2Xc.png)

Comment: In my case the hdbuserstore using the indexserver port number only (Eg.30015).  Please help me to resolve this error.